# Especificar rutas en Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, html, laravel-5, rutas

estoy haciendo el borrador de una pagina empezando por hacer las rutas.

Estas son las rutas hasta ahora:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
  return view('inicio');
});

Route::get('instituto', function () {
return view('instituto');
});
```

Este es el layout:

```
Encabezado
<br>
@yield('content')
<br>

Pie de pagina
```

Esta es la pagina de inicio:
    @extends('layout')

```
@section('content')

Esto es el inicio
<a href="{{ route('instituto')}}">instituto</a>


@endsection
```

Esta la de instituto:
    @extends('layout')

```
@section('content')

instituto

@endsection
```

Esta es mi carpeta de views:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Obtengo este error:
"Route [instituto] not defined.

Comment: Intenta de así igual aveces no me deja con route
<a href="{{ url('instituto')}}">instituto</a>

Comment: ¿qué muestra artisan route:list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error es sencillo , al crear la ruta en `Laravel` no se asigna el nombre automáticamente al menos sea una ruta tipo `resource` para poder referenciar desde la vista, por lo que debe hacerlo manualmente se la siguiente forma.

```
Route::get('instituto', function () {
    return view('instituto');
})->name('instituto'); //asignamos el nombre con el que hacemos referencia desde la vista
```

Comment: Gracias, aun no me manejo con las rutas en Laravel. Ese era el detalle, ahora funciona perfecto.